# Alternative ways of styling class-based form fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In Django, one applies CSS styling to class-based form fields in forms.py (or equivalent).

**My question:** is it impossible to do it any other way inside a Django project?

---

I'll accept the answer even if the answer is "it's impossible". Hacks and tricks are acceptable as well. Illustrative examples would be great.

*p.s. here's an example of a Django form where I've styled in the class-based form:*

```
class SampleForm(forms.Form):
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(SampleForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['description'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'btn bcg'
        self.fields['description'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'background-color:#F8F8F8; width:98%; color: #1f8cad;'
        self.fields['description'].widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters).

css.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='css')
def css(field, css):
    return field.as_widget(attrs={"style":css})
```

in your template:

```
{% load css %}
{{ item.field|css: 'width: 100px' }}
```

the result could be

```
<input id="id_field" name="field" style="width: 100px" type="text" />
```

As you can see, in style is your variable (width: 100px). You can also do it with class.